# How to use the callback after_destroy (or something similar) in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

I'm creating an application that creates polls, each poll has many poll pages, and each poll page has many question clusters, what I want to do is that when a question cluster is deleted, search every question clusters from the same page that had a higher position, and diminish 1.

This is what I tried, but it doesn't even runs:

```
after_destroy :reassign_position

private

def reassign_position
  question_clusters = QuestionCluster.where(poll_page_id: self.poll_page_id)
  question_clusters.where("position > ?", self.position)

  quest_cluster.each do |question_cluster|
    question_cluster.position -= 1
  end
end
```

How can I accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating the `question_cluster`'s attribute (`position`). Take a look:

```
def reassign_position
  question_clusters = QuestionCluster.where(poll_page_id: self.poll_page_id)
  question_clusters.where("position > ?", self.position)

  quest_cluster.each do |question_cluster|
    # actually update the question_cluster
    question_cluster.update!(position: question_cluster.position - 1) # <========
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks... but I still don't see a change... is there a way to see if the callback is running?, because when I delete a record from the rails console I see no error message, but I don't see any change in the position of the other question clusters too.

Comment: yes, as the first line of the `reassign_position` method put `binding.pry`, it will open the console and you'll be able to run the code line by line, to see where the problem is

Comment: Well, I just confirmed that the callback is not running when I delete a record, btw nice gem lol.

Comment: My stupidity, I thought .delete would also fire after_detroy, not just .destroy

Comment: @cursillosonline nope, this is the big difference between `destroy-destroy_all`/`delete-delete_all` - the latter do not fire callbacks and works directly on database